# Точка с запятой в сложной синтаксической конструкции

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сложное-предложение, точка-с-запятой

Скажите, пожалуйста, в данном предложении, представляющем собой БСП, нужно отделять точкой с запятой однородные подлежащие?

Бежали седоватые банкиры со своими жёнами; бежали талантливые дельцы, оставившие доверенных помощников в Москве, которым было поручено не терять связи с тем новым миром, который нарождался в Московском царстве(;) домовладельцы, покинувшие дома(;) промышленники; купцы(;) адвокаты(;) общественные деятели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильное предложение [М. Булгакова](https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_(%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F)_(%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,_1927).djvu/55) выглядит так.

> Бежали седоватые банкиры со своими женами,* бежали талантливые дельцы, оставившие доверенных помощников в Москве, которым было поручено не терять связи с тем новым миром, который нарождался в Московском царстве, домовладельцы, покинувшие дома верным тайным приказчикам, промышленники, купцы, адвокаты, общественные деятели.

В нем не требуются точки с запятой между однородными подлежащими. И считаю, что нигде не требуются.

Если Вы внимательно прочитаете весь абзац, то поймете, что он — практически весь абзац! — представляет собой одно большое предложение.
Булгаков не стал использовать точки с запятой между частями (пять раз "бежали"), а применил [парцелляцию](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/partselliatsiia.html) — для выделения смысловых центров, для контрастности, для привлечения внимания к некоторым деталям. (Посмотрите, есть предложение, состоящее из одного слова: "Кокотки".) Такие разношерстные группы, а цель одна — бежать, бежать...

Место, отмеченное звездочкой, — единственное, где теоретически можно было бы поставить точку с запятой (между независимыми предложениями).

[Точка с запятой](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/143-tz)